# In JavaFX TableView, how to change color of a checkbox row based on some button click event

Tags: java, javafx

I have JavaFX TableView, where I am setting a column as CheckBoxTableCell, and I want to change the background color of that cell based on some button click event, so that the color that is shown in another UI of my code, is also the background color of that cell.

I have implemented CheckBoxTableCell column as follows -

```
dtlsTableViewDisplayChannelColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().isChecked());
    dtlsTableViewDisplayChannelColumn
            .setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {
                    logger.info("AID " + observableDataList.get(param).getAid() + " changed value to "
                            + observableDataList.get(param).isChecked());
                    if (observableDataList.get(param).isChecked().get()) {
                        aidSet.add(observableDataList.get(param).getAid());
                    } else {
                        aidSet.remove(observableDataList.get(param).getAid());
                    }
                    return observableDataList.get(param).isChecked();
                }
            }));
```

And it is shown in UI as follows - 
[CheckBox in UI with Visualize button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eaas.jpg)

So when 'Visualize' button is clicked, checked CheckBox cell's background color should change to provided color value.

Please find below image, which is the expected output - 
[CheckBox in UI with background color of checked CheckBox cell changed after clicking on 'Visualize' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKA23.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi @kleopatra, I read the link - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, but I could not get a clear understanding as to what more details should I provide for this question. As I am new to this stackoverflow forum, please let me know, if I should put more code or more information about the question.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea which part of "write a short standalone runnable example that demonstrates what you are after and how it doesn't work" is hard to understand ..

Comment: Post a code snippet in your question which includes a class extenting `Application` and a `main` method that runs it. Add to it the necessary minimum code that demonstrates the problem (the table and part that changes color). When you are done preparing it, copy paste it to a new project and run it yourself to see if the problem occurs. If you can't do that, so can't we.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for... I'm going to pretend like I understand your code and show you where the edit should go:

```
dtlsTableViewDisplayChannelColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().isChecked());
    dtlsTableViewDisplayChannelColumn
            .setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {
                    logger.info("AID " + observableDataList.get(param).getAid() + " changed value to "
                            + observableDataList.get(param).isChecked());
                    if (observableDataList.get(param).isChecked().get()) {
                        aidSet.add(observableDataList.get(param).getAid());
                        observableDataList.get(param).setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;"); //<--- This changes the color of the specific checkbox 
                        //Note: I assume "param" calls the specific checkbox in the checkbox list "observableDataList"
                    } else {
                        aidSet.remove(observableDataList.get(param).getAid());
                    }
                    return observableDataList.get(param).isChecked();
                }
            }));
```